# How to Mirror an NSMutableArray?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmutablearray

How does one mirror an `NSMutableArray` (first element becomes last one, second becomes second to last, ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-[NSMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:]`.

So, if your array is called `a`:

```
NSUInteger c = [a count];
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < (c / 2); ++i) {
    [a exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:(c - i) - 1];
}
```

Comment: +1, As you mirrored the array itself.

Comment: There's a small error btw : it should be `c - i - 1` since `c - 0` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSArray* reversedArray = [[orgArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Comment: This will not change your original array, however, i.e the mirroring won't be in-place.